# Offline mode, encrypt/decrypt video file on mobile app ios, android

Tags: android, ios, encryption, offline-mode

i’m looking for any tips to encrypt video file while downloading in mobile app, and decrypt it locally(without access to the internet). I’m trying to improve my own app with offline mode but i couldnt find the rightt method for both ios and adroind app, any ideas or suggests? The best example would be a netflix app but i realize that there were hundreds of engineers working on it, in my case I only have myself, soo u know;)
maybe there is a simple solution that I haven’t found yet

Comment: DRM (what you are trying to do) is inherently impossible - the sooner you accept that, the more time you will save.

Answer (score -2):

you can use an algorithm like RSA to encrypt and decrypt using public and private keys.

Visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=plxMklEvlCU

to see how RSA works

Note:- There are many algorithms, you just have to implement any one of those

Comment: You can encrypt with every algorithm you can find all day long and the user who has your app can decrypt it at his leisure.